# How to connect Spring boot application with U2 universe database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, universe, u2

I am using Spring boot version 2.6 , i want to use U2 universe as database. My question is how to setting a connection in application.properties?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Install Rocket software and download unijdbc.jar(you can find the jar inside the path \U2\UniDK\jdbc\lib).

STEP 2 : Create Lib folder in your spring boot project and put the jar inside the folder.

STEP 3 : go to pom.xml file and add below dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>uni-jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>uni-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.161.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/uni-jdbc.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

STEP 4 : In application.properties file provide the datasourse details.

```
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:rs-u2://hostname/Account?dbmstype=UNIDATA
     spring.datasource.username=username
     spring.datasource.password=Password
     spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.rs.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver
```

Make sure your URL details is correct.
jdbc:rs-u2://"+host+"/"+account+"?dbmstype="+dbmstype+

STEP 5: to check the connection, run your application in debug level by adding below properties in application.properties.

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG

Comment: URL should be in below format

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:rs-u2://hostname//Account?dbmstype=UNIDATA

Dailect will be 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

you can see the more information regarding Dailect class in below url

https://ri-doc-lts-html5.identitymgmt.net/en/jdbc-drivers.html